# Passing data in Reactjs using material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Thanks in advance for any help.

I am developing a web application that uses Reactjs and material-UI to display energy use data for multiple farms.

I wish to click a button on the main page and that takes me to another page for an individual farm to view its data.

Here is the code, which uses the NavLink component to redirect the page:

```
{/*Farm B*/}
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader
              color="danger"
              stats
              icon
              sensorValue="43.27"
              cardName="Farm B"
            >
              <CardIcon color="primary">
                <SvgIcon
                  component={BarnIcon}
                  viewBox="0 0 980.000000 980.000000"
                />
              </CardIcon>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardFooter stats>
              **<NavLink to="/admin/dashboard" activeClassName="selected">**
                GO
              </NavLink>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
```

From here, when it lands on the requested page i.e., for farm B, how do I send a string as a variable to the second page so that instead of having X number of individual pages for individual farms, I can simply specify a variable - say 'A' or 'B' etc and it loads the same page with dynamic data.

Thanks.

Comment: in short, you want to send some data to the `/admin/dashboard`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - just simply a string

Comment: I think using url would be the best to do that. But using a query parameter ('/admin/dashboard?farm=A') or url itself (`/admin/dashboard/A/`) is your decision.

Comment: @acbay would that mean I would still need individual scripts for each of the farms and supply a query parameter for each one?

Comment: no. you can reach query parameter or or url match parameters from your component.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```
<Navlink 
    to={{
       pathname: '/admin/dashboard/'
       someString: 'hello world'
    }}
>Go</Navlink>
```

access it with `props.location.someString`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt seem to work here is the error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
Dashboard
C:/xampp/htdocs/material-dashboard-react-master/src/views/Dashboard/Dashboard_farm1.js:47
  44 |   stats
  45 |   icon
  46 |   sensorValue="28.93"
> 47 |   cardName={this.props.location.name}
     | ^  48 | >
  49 |   <CardIcon color="info">
  50 |     <SvgIcon

Comment: its as if the variable is not getting to the second page...

Comment: please specify props in your dashboard component

Comment: const Dashboard = (props) => {} or class Dashboard extends React.component {}, for functional component ( props ) and for class based  ( this.props )

Comment: thanks again. If I were to add the "Dashboard extends React,Component{}", I already have the constructor: "export default function Dashboard() {}". So how would I handle that?

Comment: export default function Dashboard(props) {} <-- add props in `(props)`

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by simply either define and passing a path variable that its dynamic to the `/admin/dashboard` URL
ie you will need to do

```
<NavLink to=`/admin/dashboard/stringtopass` activeClassName="selected">
```

And with this you will also need to modify the route listening for that URL to accept a path variable to be of the form

```
 <Route path='/admin/dashboard/:pathvairable' exact component={Dashboard} />
```

If your Dashboard component which you want to use the sent variable in is written using hooks you will simply need to do
`let { pathvairable } = useParams();` supposing you had the line `import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'` in your imports

However if you are dealing with normal classical components, You will need to get the variable using
`this.props.match.params.pathvairable`

You will be able to read more [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this it works best.

```
//First Create Route Path
<Route path="/items/:itemId" component={Items} / >

// your link creation

const newTo = { 
  pathname: "/admin/dashboard", 
  String: 'hello bro' 
};
      <CardFooter stats>
          <NavLink to={newTo} activeClassName="selected">
            GO
          </NavLink>
        </CardFooter>

// In your CardFooter Component, you can access the data like this

this.props.match.params.itemId // this is items id 
this.props.location.String// this is Par1
```